# How to fill gap between garage floor and driveway

Tags: concrete, sealing, gap

I have a concrete garage floor and a section of concrete driveway next to it. Over the years the driveway has settled a little bit and the gap between the two is probably close to an inch wide and several inches deep. At one point it looks like someone put rubber in it.

I'm looking to fill this gap with the proper material. What would that material be and how do I apply it?

Comment: The 'rubber' is probably bitumen which is commonly used as an expansion joint to prevent cracking caused by thermal expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very common gap size for concrete swimming pool decks, check a local pool store for wood, plastic and rubber expansion joint fillers. Thinner Concrete Pavers could also be cut into strips and dropped or stuffed in.

Otherwise, there's no problem with filling (and ramping, if desired) the gap with concrete or cement. The filler won't have any interaction with either slab, since they're fully separated and new cement bonds extremely weakly to old cement.